# Bind text input value on change event - React Native + Redux

Tags: javascript, forms, reactjs, redux

I'm creating form in React Native and Redux. I added `TextInput` and want to change the state of this field in Reducer. I have a trouble, because I don't know how to add `(change) => this.setState({change})` function to my Redux architecture. I use combine reducers and have no idea how to bind that value. 
Saying in short, I need to gain default behaviour of the `TextInput` on change function but I have to use Redux to do it.

Form.js

```
const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
  return {
      changeNameInput: () => dispatch({type: 'CHANGE_NAME_INPUT'})
  };
};

const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return {
      change: state.changeNameInput.change
  };
};

class Form extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View>
         <FormLabel>Name</FormLabel>
         <TextInput
            onChangeText={this.props.changeNameInput}
            value={this.props.change}
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Reducer.js

```
const initialState = {
    change: 'Your name'
   };

   const changeinputReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
     switch (action.type) { 
       case 'CHANGE_NAME_INPUT':

  //Problem

         return {...state, change: '????' };
        default:
         return state;
     }
   };

   export default changeinputReducer;
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For passing value from TextInput to reducer, you need to change in dispatch function:

```
const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
  return {
      changeNameInput: (text) => dispatch({type: 'CHANGE_NAME_INPUT', text})
  };
};
```

and in your reducer change it to

```
const changeinputReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
     switch (action.type) { 
       case 'CHANGE_NAME_INPUT':

  //Solution

         return {...state, change: action.text };
        default:
         return state;
     }
   };
```

Hope it worked..

Comment: Awesome.What makes different if i use

`onChangeText={this.props.changeNameInput.bind(this)}`